# Visual Studio 2010 - Change localhost to custom domain

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localhost

How do I change so that debugging doesn't happen on localhost:randomNumber but on a custom domain like my.testsite.com:randomNumber?

I've added the domain to the hosts file and I can manually change the url when debugging from localhost to my.testsite.com, but can I make VS start at my.testsite.com from the get-go instead of localhost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes... you do that in the project options.  You can specify a custom startup URL as well as a fixed port if you want.  The built-in VS server will follow whatever you type there, then your hosts file will take care of the mappings for you.

Comment: Thank you. Follow-up question. I have a login page that redirects the user to their previous page after logging in. This redirect goes back to localhost and not the custom domain. Can I do something about that?

Comment: Make sure any embedded links in your page don't list 'Localhost' or anything like that.  Keep everything relative or absolute, but without the host name.  There should be no reason your app redirects back to localhost unless a) you've linked something via Localhost, or b) you've started from Localhost.  Again, it shouldn't arbitrarily go there.