# change localhost to another domain name

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to change localhost name in visual studio to my own name for example `jeson.com`

I search and find some topic [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810528/visual-studio-2010-change-localhost-to-custom-domain) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270516/change-localhost-domain-when-running-locally)
I change my hosts file to

> 127.0.0.1    jeson.com
>      ::1          jeson.com

However, this method does not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IIS -> Create Site`

`Binding -> jeson.com`

`Project -> properties -> Web -> Use Local IIS server -> ProjectUrl: http://jeson.com`

Comment: thank you for answer but i want to do this from existing website that is in C:\Users\~jeson\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1 path .when i give that path in iis as physical path and then brows website ,iis give me "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" and when i want to run web site in VS in debug/without debug server give me error "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname"...what happened????

Comment: i use asp.net web site...but this setting is available on asp.net web application!!

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to the bottom of your hosts file:

```
  127.0.0.1     jeson.com
```

Leave out the:

```
::1 jeson.com
```

if it does not work, try restarting httpd

Comment: i restart my webserver ...but not take effect!

Comment: well this is the way its usually done, there seems to be some other problem affecting you, which i cant say from here. Sorry man, you may have to spend some time investigating and googling stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

change your localhost name to domain name.Go to this path.
`File Path-> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`
 This is an example of the hosts file
`127.0.0.1  localhost loopback`
`::1        localhost`
`127.0.0.1       localhost`
`127.0.0.1  facebooktest.com`
restart your server..
[Read this](http://www.gkdreamz.com/apache-server/how-to-change-your-default-locahost-name-in-hosts-file/)

Comment: Late to the party, but as of Oct 30, 2013, that link appears to have been compromised, unless you like Luis(sp?) Vuitton(sp?) handbags.