# ASP.net website administration issuse

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679772/change-localhost-to-another-domain-name) i change 'localhost" to jeson.com
for example when i run login.aspx web page in viusal studio IDE ,browser show me http://jeson.com/login.aspx
ok.every thing seem ok but when i want to use asp.net website administration tools(website menu > ASP.Net confuguration) it run on fllowing URL:

> localhost:49917/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx
>   applicationPhysicalPath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\&applicationUrl=/

now when i want to create new user in this tools it give me erro

```
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Invalid viewstate. Client IP: 127.0.0.1 Port: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0 ViewState: ...
```

i use  http://jeson.com:49917 Instead localhost and every thing become  OK
but problem is **every time that is want to use this tool i must change loclahost to jeson.com handly**
but i want to do this automaticaly

Comment: Do you have change and remove localhost ? or add the jeson.com after localhost ?

Comment: YES! in question i link another question that say complete story about changing localhost to jeson.ocm.i add jeson.com after localhost.is the way to take affect for all localhost??(such as localhost:49917 that ASP.net WAT use it)