# How to change the "localhost" to a domain name in a mongodb connection string?

Tags: mongodb

so I just finished building my website using mongodb. Now I just bought a domain name and I want to change the `localhost` in the connection string below to my domain name (Let's say `example.com`). This is how the connection string looks like with `localhost` as it's hostname:

```
mongodb://nspeedzy:****@localhost:27017
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
mongodb://nspeedzy:****@example.com:27017
```

Is there any way to make the mongodb connection string look like how it looks as mentioned above?

Comment: One thing to note, if you have your MongoDB database on the same box you are running your application on, it's better to not have your DB exposed to public traffic.  If your application can access it through the local loopback address it ensures that there's less of a chance someone could break into your datastore.  They would first have to gain access to your server and then crack your password inside MongoDB, instead of being able to brute force it through the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change a local file called :

- /etc/hosts in linux
- C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts in Windows
- or even more detail for Mac OS [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)

You must include an alias in that file for your localhost:

```
   127.0.0.1     example.com
```

And using example.com in your application.

Anyway you can review some [other questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679772/change-localhost-to-another-domain-name) related with this topic.