# Visual Studio 2010 change from localhost to full computer name/domain

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localhost

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I would like change debugging environment from the localhost to my full computer name/domain. Does anyone have some step by step instructions on how to do this? (I would also like to set it up as the default for all new projects plus how to change it in existing projects). I am new to using visual studio and programming in general.

I found this post [Visual Studio 2010 - Change localhost to custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810528/visual-studio-2010-change-localhost-to-custom-domain) in the forum but it wasn't clear to me on how to make the change. I went to the project properties web tab and attempted to set up local IIS Web server but got the following error:

"ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server. You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly."

I am not ever sure if that was the correct way of going about doing this. I just need my debug url address to go from:

"http://localhost:53674/Projectname.aspx"

to:

"http://computername.pag-domain.webname.org/Projectname.aspx"

Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Our IT came to the rescue - he fixed some issues with the ASP.NET not accessing 4.0 correctly and then I set up the "Use Local IIS Web server" correctly this time and it worked like a charm...

Comment: You should answer your own question trying to give all the possible details and accept it. This way, when someone else have the same problem, he will be able to use this question to solve it. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Our IT came to the rescue — he fixed some issues with the ASP.NET not accessing 4.0 correctly. Then I set up the "Use Local IIS Web server" correctly and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the iis web server, I am not really sure what was done...our IT department worked on that. For setting up the local IIS webserver in visual studio I did the following: In the web project properties, under the web tab, I choose "Use Local IIS Web server, in the project URL, I put the full computer domain and told it to create a virtual directory.